# Why are all right bones not connected with the mesh?

Tags: armature, bones

I'm new to blender and I recently made a model by my self and today I‘m finally going to connect it with bones! It looks all right:

[image]

But look what happens to the arms and legs:

[image]

Why are all right bones not connected with the mesh?

Comment: perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Perhaps select your object and in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups, on the menu on the right of the list, there is a drowdown menu, click on Delete All Groups, then reparent With Automatic Weight? Not sure though...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange! To get helpful answers quickly please consider adding a blend file if possible. Also describe how you reached the current result and what steps you have tried to solve it so far. You can edit your question to add additional information. Have a great time on Blender Stackexchange and happy blending!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,i found out that i DIDN'T apply the mirror modifier!stupid me,now it works perfectly!

[image]